# Find all permutation of a series where no adjacent elements are same?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinations, permutation, dynamic-programming

We are given a list of numbers where every number either occurs by itself or it occurs in duplicate. The task now is to find total number of permutation in which we can arrange this list of numbers so that no two adjacent elements on the list will be the same. The crux is to do it efficiently and thats why I am looking for an algorithm that uses dynamic programming. The length can be very large upto 5000 elements and thats why generating all cases and checking if a case is correct or not is not a good idea. We only want the number of total permutations and not the actual permutations of the list.

Example Case:
[1,1,2,2]

Output: 2

[1,2,1,2] and [2,1,2,1]

Example Case:
[1,2,3,3]

Output: 6

[3,1,2,3], [3,2,1,3], [1,3,2,3],[2,3,1,3],[3,1,3,2] and [3,2,3,1]

Example Case: [1,1,2,2,3,3]

Output: 30

Comment: Could you show any own efforts?

Comment: Maybe start out with a traditional generator and then modify that to deal with the extra constraint?

Comment: start writing brute force first, then think about how to optimize, try to find common sub problems.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys. So I did work on problem before I came out here. The technique that I came up with is following. Count all the permutations. Then at a time remove duplicates of first then remove duplicates of second and add the occurrences of similar subtracts and keep doing it for all. I am getting stuck at the point of recurrence establishment that is to find a common subproblem.

Comment: Ok I also think of something else but I don't know how to accommodate it. The idea is that I have some numbers that are not repeating and the permutations of all these numbers will be size!. Then I can accommodate duplicates at a time but what confused me is that how to add duplicates at a time and come up with a sub problem.

Answer (score 3):

This problem might be solved using [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

If number of single items is `s` and number of double item pairs is `d`, then overall number of permutations is

```
A0 = (s + 2 * d)! / 2^d
```

Now we must **subtract** number of permutation where one pair is adjacent. There are

```
P1 = (s+2*d-1)! / 2^(d-1)
```

such permutations for every doubled element, and

```
A1 = d *(s+2*d-1)! / 2^(d-1)
```

such permutations for all doubled elements

Now we must **add** number of permutation where two pairs are adjacent. 
There are

```
P2 = (s+2*d-2)! / 2^(d-2)
```

such permutations for every pair of doubled elements, and

```
A2 = C(d,2) * (s+2*d-2)! / 2^(d-2)
```

permutations for all possible pairs of doubled elements (where `C(n,k)` is binomial coefficient, number of combinations).

Continue this procedure, changing sign, so

```
A(k){k=1..d} = (-1)^k * C(d, k) * (s+2*d-k)! / 2^(d-k)
```

and sum this sequence to get final result

For your last example (`s=0,d=3`):

```
 6!/2^3 - 3*5!/2^2 + 3*4!/2 - 3! = 
 720/8  - 360/4 +    72/2   - 6  = 
  90    - 90     +   36     - 6  = 30
```

Comment: Thanks MBo. I will try to use this to also come up with a memoization technique. I did think of a memoization criteria or sub problem as discussed above but I am still working on making a final memoized solution or recurrence. The idea is that I will look at a given length and then I will look at that at max how many occurence of error or pair is together. Meaning that if my array is [1,2,1,2]. Then with length 0 to 4 how many are there with error of [11] and [22] together. Then with either [11] or [22] alone and finally neither and with neither alone at the maximum length should be my answer.

Comment: Yes, dynamic programming approach is possible but perhaps complex. You have number of good sequences of length K ending with element X and can build sequence with length K+1 adding any element except for X and those already used - but keeping "used" might be not so easy (I did not try)

Comment: I will try the approach of dynamic programming and will share it here once I have a solution or I reach a point where I am stuck and maybe you can guide accordingly.

Comment: I described I-E principle approach because believe it is simpler here

Comment: Yes. That was very easy to understand. I am actually practicing dynamic programming and want to learn how to formulate sub problems and that is why I want to try DP for this.